# SQL tables loop using id from previous loop

Tags: oracle

This is probably a stupid question but im trying to make a loop that will iterate through w_info_vrstice_setup and fill in a table with basically copies with just slight changes (banka := p_banka_v) but i have to use its id in the next table w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup and do the same thing (fill in a table with copies) but using the id from the table mentioned before.

```
   is
     w_info_vrstice_sif_setup tab_ol_mv_sif_setup%rowtype;
     w_info_vrstice_setup tab_ol_mv_setup%rowtype;
     w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup tab_ol_mv_skupina_setup%rowtype;
     
       cursor c is
         select a.* 
           from tab_ol_mv_sif_setup a
        where a.banka = p_banka_iz;

       cursor d is
         select b.* 
           from tab_ol_mv_setup b
        where b.banka = p_banka_iz;

        
       cursor e is
         select k.* 
           from tab_ol_mv_skupina_setup k
        where k.banka = p_banka_iz;


 begin
   for i in c loop     
     w_info_vrstice_sif_setup := i;
     w_info_vrstice_sif_setup.tvoril := null;
     w_info_vrstice_sif_setup.tvoril_datum := null;
     w_info_vrstice_sif_setup.id_prijave := null;     
     w_info_vrstice_sif_setup.banka := p_banka_v;
         
     insert into tab_ol_mv_sif_setup 
     values w_info_vrstice_sif_setup;
     
     end loop;
 
     for j in d loop     
       w_info_vrstice_setup := j;
       w_info_vrstice_setup.tvoril := null;
       w_info_vrstice_setup.tvoril_datum := null;
       w_info_vrstice_setup.id_prijave := null;  
       w_info_vrstice_setup.banka := p_banka_v;
        
       insert into tab_ol_mv_setup
       values w_info_vrstice_setup;
      
       
       for l in e loop       
         w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup := l; 
         dbms_output.put_line(w_info_vrstice_setup.id);
         w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup.id_mv := w_info_vrstice_setup.id;
         w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup.tvoril := null;
         w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup.tvoril_datum := null;
         w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup.id_prijave := null;   
         w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup.banka := p_banka_v;

         insert into tab_ol_mv_skupina_setup
         values w_info_vrstice_skupina_setup;
       
     end loop; 
   end loop;    
 end;
```

This is what i made for now and the first to inserts work. But the last one is the problem as mentioned above.

Note: i get unique constrain error because the third table loops with the first id from the second table

Comment: This is a poor design in the context of RDBMS: RDBMS works well on sets, not individual records. Do not use for loop, join all those tables together, calculate everything you need and do `insert ... select ...`

Comment: Your queries are not correlated with each other - there is no predicate in those cursors using a value from a parent cursor. Therefore by executing them in a nested fashion, you are inserting the same rows over and over again. Also you haven't defined `p_banka_v` and you also aren't actually using anything you pull from the cursor other than the row index.

If the tables aren't really in a parent-child-child relationship with each other, don't nest the loops. In fact, don't use looping at all, just have three `INSERT...SELECT` statements.

Comment: If you *do* need nesting for some reason, you can declare your cursors with parameters and pass in a parameter when opening it, using a value from one of the parent loops.